# Need help spotting an SQL syntax error in a small query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, relational-database

I'm getting an SQL syntax error "around line 5" of the following code..

```
SELECT artists.name, albums.title, genres.genre
    FROM artist_album
        JOIN artists ON artist_album.artist_id = artists.id
        JOIN albums ON artist_album.album_id = albums.album_id
    FROM album_genre
        JOIN genres ON album_genre.genre_id = genres.genre_id
        WHERE genres.genre = 'Pop' OR genres.genre = 'Rock'
```

What I am trying to find is all artists in the database who released a ‘Rock’ or a ‘Pop’ album. The query should return artist name, album title, and album genre..

My tables are:

```
albums
    album_id
    released
    title

artist
    id
    name

genres
    genre_id
    genre

album_genre
    album_id
    genre_id

artist_album
   album_id
   artist_id
```

I am very new to SQL, so i'm sure what I am doing wrong is something I am unaware of.. but after digging around the internet for a bit I cannot see what I may syntactically be doing wrong.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have two "from"s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it should be

```
JOIN album_genre ON album_genre.album_id = albums.album_id
```

instead of

```
FROM album_genre
```

Comment: That.. actually makes a lot of sense.. I don't know what I was thinking :|   thanks Jasen!

Answer (score 0):

This is your SQL:

```
SELECT artists.name, albums.title, genres.genre
From artists join artist_album On artist_album.artist_id = artists.id
join albums ON artist_album.album_id = albums.album_id
join album_genre ON album_genre.album_id =albums.album_id
JOIN genres ON album_genre.genre_id = genres.genre_id
        WHERE genres.genre = 'Pop' OR genres.genre = 'Rock'
```